# Measuring the window offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, offset

Is there a way to measure the offset of the window in jQuery, in order than I might compare the positions of a 'fixed' element and a relatively positioned one?

I need to be able to tell how far the window is scrolled so I can use the figure to calculate the difference between the height of the fixed element (which is relative to the viewport top) and the relative object (which is relative to the top of the document)

Comment: example markup would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be. I am trying to extract the relative scroll position of a document in a browser. Any page mark up would be valid example code in this instance.

Comment: refer [**this**](http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html) link you will get your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(window).scrollLeft()` can be used to find scroll positions.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain Javascript without jQuery should be `window.pageXOffset` and `window.pageYOffset`, which return the number of pixels offset by scrolling.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

Answer (score 0):

document.body.offsetWidth;

and

document.body.offsetHeight;

By using these javascript functions you can get actual width and height of the browser window

Comment: this doesn't change as my window scrolls into new positions. I am essentially looking for scroll positions.

Comment: if ((jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery("#maindiv").height() - jQuery(window).height())) {
             // try this code 
            }